# Boostrap 3 make floating panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap I have a grid structure with 3 panels as in the attached image:

[image]

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel">
         <!-- This is table panel on the left -->
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="panel">
         <!-- Section 1 panel -->
      </div>
   </div>
<div>

<div class=" row">
   <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel">
         <!-- Section 2 panel -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Of course as the number of rows in the table increases, the Section 3 panel goes down... How can I make the Section 3 panel stay below the Section 1 panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move your panel 3 after your panel 1 like so:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel">
         ...
         This is table panel on the left
         ...
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="panel">
         ...
         Section 1 panel
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
         ...
         Section 2 panel
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
<div>
```